# Ошибки при обращении в таблице БД в SPRING

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

Продолжаю изучать SPRING-BOOT.
Создаю форму регистрации пользователей, вот код:

```
@Entity

//на usr ругается: Cannot resolve table 'usr'
@Table(name = "usr") 
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String username;
private String password;
private boolean active;
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

//тут ругается: "Cannot resolve table 'user_role'" и "Cannot resolve column 'user_id' "
@CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

программа запускается, и вроде как даже работает, но IDEA ругается на три поля(в коде выше показаны эти поля и ошибки), причем они подсвечены красным цветом, но компиляция проходит. В чем тут проблема?
Версия JDK 8, Maven 3.3.9, Spring-Boot 2.2.2, БД использую postgresql

Comment: Проблема в том что вы обращаете на это внимание. Это часто вылазит, просто не парьтесь, если все работает.

Comment: IDEA ругается из-за того, что не может понять, откуда вы берете эти столбцы. Чтобы это убрать, вам нужно назначить Data Source. При наведении на эти красные подчеркивания, идея предложит это сделать. А там просто в Data Source выбрать свое подключение к БД. Но, скорее всего, это работает только в Ultimate версии, потому что в Community, насколько мне известно, нельзя через идею подключиться к БД. В любом случае эти предупреждения никак не влияют на выполнение программы, поэтому не беспокойтесь об этом

Answer (score 0):

Нужно настроить Data Sources. Либо в Idea убрать поддержку JPA в проекте, ее можно потом опять добавить, если что.